# How to authorize iTunes in Mavericks (OS X 10.9)?

Tags: itunes, imac

I've got my new iMac OS X 10.9
I'm using iTunes on my new iMac, running Mavericks. I would like to download music/movies which I've purchased.

But then a pop-up displays:

> Your computer is not authorized; You must authorize this computer
>   before you can download previous purchases.

How can I authorize my computer?
'

Answer (score 2):

1. Open iTunes
2. Find the **Store** menu
3. Select "**Authorize This Computer**" and enter your Apple ID and password.

Comment: where is this "store menu" i have opened every menu in itunes and have found nothing that says Authorize this computer. OS 10.9